# Finding all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ which $a^b=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to deal with this question, here we consider only the principal branch of complex logarithm $\log$.
If $b=0$, then for all $a\in\mathbb{C}-0$,  $a^b=1$, $(a,b)\in(\mathbb{C}-0,0)$.

If $b\in\mathbb{C}-0$, by definition, $a^b=\exp(b\cdot \log(a))=1$, it follows
$$b\cdot \log a=k\cdot2\pi i, \text{where} \space k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
that is,
$b\cdot\log(|a|)+i\cdot Arg (a)=k\cdot2\pi i$, where $Arg$ is the principal argument of complex number, $Arg(a)\in (-\pi,\pi]$, $\log|a|$ is the real logarithm of the modulus of $a$.

I tried to express $b\in\mathbb{C}-0$ as $b=b_1+ib_2$, $b_{1,2}\in\mathbb{R}$, so
$$(b_1+ib_2)(b\cdot\log(|a|)+i\cdot Arg (a))=(b_1-b_2\cdot Arg(a))+i(b_1Arg(a)+b_2\log(|a|))=k\cdot2\pi i$$, where $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Then we have
$b_1-b_2\cdot Arg(a)=0$ and $b_1Arg(a)+b_2\log(|a|))=k\cdot2\pi i$, now I'm stuck in here. Could anyone give me a hint? Thank you so much.

Comment: branches are unrelated to this question

Comment: the pairs can be parametrized as $(\exp(2k\pi i/b),b)$ for any $b \ne 0, k \in \mathbb Z$ and of course the trivial ones $(a,0), a \ne 0$, where $\exp z=\sum z^k/k!$; not sure that anything simpler can be achieved

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \left[re^{i\theta}\right]^{x + iy} = 1 : -\pi < \theta \leq \pi \implies $

$\displaystyle \left(r^x e^{-y\theta}\right) \times \left(r^{iy}e^{ix\theta}\right) = 1 \implies $

- $\displaystyle r^x e^{-y\theta} = 1 \implies x\log(r) = y\theta$.
- $\displaystyle (2\pi) ~\text{divides}~ \left\{ ~[y\log(r)] + [x\theta] ~\right\}.$

Therefore, if $r$ and $\theta$ are construed to be fixed known values, and divisibility by $(2\pi)$ is construed to be equivalent to $2k\pi$, where $k$ is some fixed known integer, then you have a system of $2$ linear equations in the $2$ unknowns $x$ and $y$.

**Edit**
If the resulting determinant is $\neq 0$, then there will be a unique $(x,y)$ solution, for each value of $k$.

The determinant is $\log^2(r) + \theta^2.$  With $\theta$ required to be in the $(-\pi,\pi]$ interval, the determinant will equal $0$ if and only if $r = 1$ and $\theta = 0.$